# Store/Retrieve a timestamp with or without timezone

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp-with-timezone

I wanted to test some differences with the timestamp and timestamp with time zone fields. But I came across something I can't really understand why it works like this.

I have the following setup:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_test_timezones (
    first_date timestamp with time zone,
    second_date timestamp 
)
```

I have inserted some testdata:

```
insert into tbl_test_timezones (first_date, second_date) values (now(), now());
```

Now I wanted to check the differences between the two fields when I do a select

```
select 
    first_date, 
    first_date at time zone 'Europe/Brussels' as first_date_wt, 
    second_date, 
    second_date at time zone 'Europe/Brussels' as second_date_wt
from tbl_test_timezones

which gives me the following result

first_date:     2016-10-03 07:03:16.63818+00    
first_date_wt:  2016-10-03 09:03:16.63818   
second_date:    2016-10-03 07:03:16.63818   
second_date_wt: 2016-10-03 05:03:16.63818+00
```

**Question 1**

I'm wondering why second_date_wt is doing -2 instead of +2 like first_date_wt?

**Question 2**

Let's say my application stores the timestamps with the time zone and the user wants to get some records with this timestamp. Do you have to store some kind of user setting for the user where he can enter his timezone and always include this in the select query when retrieving them? Or do you prefer to just get it and do that timezone stuff in the client application?

for example:

```
select start_date at time zone (
    select user_time_zone from tbl_user_settings where user_id = 2
)
from tbl_projects
```

or do just

```
select start_date 
from tbl_projects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to question 1**

These two values have a different meaning.

```
first_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Brussels'
```

answers: What does the wall clock show in Brussels at this point in time?

```
second_date AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Brussels'
```

answers: At what point in time does the wall clock in Brussels show this value?

**Answer to question 2**

The best way to do this is by setting the configuration parameter `TimeZone` to the time zone of the client application. Then all `timestamp with time zone` values will be shown in this time zone, and `timestamp without time zone` values will be interpreted as values in this timezone:

```
SHOW TimeZone;

   TimeZone
---------------
 Europe/Vienna
(1 row)

SELECT
   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2016-10-01 00:00:00 UTC' AS "midnight at UTC",
   CAST(
      TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE '2016-10-01 00:00:00'
      AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
   ) AS "midnight local";

    midnight at UTC     |     midnight local
------------------------+------------------------
 2016-10-01 02:00:00+02 | 2016-10-01 00:00:00+02
(1 row)

SET TimeZone = 'America/Los_Angeles';

SELECT
   TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2016-10-01 00:00:00 UTC' AS "midnight at UTC",
   CAST(
      TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE '2016-10-01 00:00:00'
      AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
   ) AS "midnight local";

    midnight at UTC     |     midnight local
------------------------+------------------------
 2016-09-30 17:00:00-07 | 2016-10-01 00:00:00-07
(1 row)
```

Comment: the answers on the first question is an easy way to remember the difference, thanks! Also didn't know you could set a timezone with the SET keyword. Great! But what would you do when your clients are in different timezones, do you always do SET TIMEZONE = xxxxx for every query then?

Comment: If one session has to serve customers in different time zones, like in a connection pool, you'd have to set the time zone every time you switch customers. But you'd have to do the same thing in your application if you handle time zones in your application code, right?

Comment: In my case I'm having a REST API where the client can connect too. So if I store the timestamps as 'timestamp with zone' and I get the data, I only have to set the client application to the correct time zone to show the correct time, right? No need for my backend to know in which timezone the enduser is?

Comment: The setting is relevant whenever a `timestamp with time zone` is converted to a string. Is your Hawaiian customer happy to get her result as `2016-10-03 07:03:16.63818+00`?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean that the setting is relevant when it's converted to as string to show it in a list, a printout or whatever. But I also have this calendar which has a timezone setting so I can just get the timestamp without doing SET Timezone = xxxx and set the timezone on the calendar in the client application. I guess I'm thinking in the right way?

Comment: Perhaps --- I can't really help you there because I don't know the calendar. I'd try it out.